# Codename One theme designer not launching

Tags: java, eclipse, codenameone

I have just installed Codename One (via the eclipse marketplace) on Eclipse Oxygen, with Java 8 under a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I followed the "getting started" instructions in order to create a new project, but the "theme.res" file does not appear under the "src" directory. When I run the application, an exception is generated since the "theme.res" file is not found. If I comment out the line in the init() method initializing the theme, then the application runs in the emulator.

If I create a demo project (which does include a .res file in the "src" folder) and I double click on the .res file, then the theme editor does not launch. Maybe these two problems are related?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the builtin OpenJDK instead of the Oracle JDK.

The problem is that Open JDK doesn't support JavaFX and we need some JavaFX features for things such as webkit support, media etc. We print out a warning when we run the simulator but that might not be noticeable enough. Not sure if there is anywhere we can put a better warning.

Comment: Great! This solved the problem. My bad, I did not notice the warning when running the simulator. Thank you so much!